# What is the use of @Entity annotation when entity not included in persistence unit

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, entity

I have few JPA annotated entity classes in my sample application i am building and almost all are specified in the persistence unit to be managed by the JPA provider.

For those entity which are annotated but not included in the persistence.xml:

1. What is the use of the entity annotation ?
2. Do they still map to the tables in the database ?
3. Since they are not managed by provider, how can i use those entities to persist data?

Appreciate any answers to clarify my understanding.

Answer (score 4):

JPA will include any class annotated with `@Entity` in the persistence management setup. You don't need `persistence.xml`if you use annotations.

Cheers,

Comment: After removing any reference to the entity classes in the persistence-unit in persistence.xml, the application hits an exception: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NamedQuery of name: Article.findByArticleid not found.`

Comment: Sounds like you had a named query in your `persistence.xml` move that to the `@Entity` using  the `@NamedQuery` annotation. In general, anything you had in `persistence.xml` should be converted to annotation-based config, if you wish to do without it.

Comment: It works after adding `<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>` element in the `<persistence-unit>` in persistence.xml as suggested by @datanucleus

Answer (score 1):

`JPA` scans automatically for classes annotated with `@Entity` and includes them.

Comment: not necessarily. Depends on "exclude-unlisted-classes" and whether using J2EE or J2SE.